# Targeting multi input inside a form for addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I would like to set up an `.addEventListener` every time any input bar is selected with a click (`focus`). I tried to target it with `getElementsByTagName('input')` but also with `querySelectorAll()` but it does not work.. The final goal is to print an `alert` when the field is left empty. many thanks

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input').addEventListener('focus', function () {
    console.log("on focus")
})
```

```html
   <form action="" class="signUp">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <!-- <label for="fname"></label> -->
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="fname" name="user_name" placeholder="First Name">
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- <label for="lname"></label> -->
            <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="lname" name="user_name" placeholder="Last Name">
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- <label for="email"></label> -->
            <input type="email" onfocus="this.value=''" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email Address">
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- <label for="password"></label> -->
            <input type="password" onfocus="this.value=''" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </li>
          <li class="button">
            <button type="submit" id="buttonClaim">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need call `getElementsByTagName` on `document`, not `document.document`. `document.document` isn't a thing.

Second, `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. You might notice that `Elements` is plural here unlike `getElementById`. With an array, you need to select one element by using an index. Since you want every input to have a listener, you can iterate through the array with a [`for... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Finally, the event needs to be lowercase like `focus`, not `Focus`

```js
for (let v of document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
  v.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    console.log("on focus")
  });
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="signUp">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="fname"></label> -->
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="fname" name="user_name" placeholder="First Name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="lname"></label> -->
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="lname" name="user_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="email"></label> -->
      <input type="email" onfocus="this.value=''" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="password"></label> -->
      <input type="password" onfocus="this.value=''" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <button type="submit" id="buttonClaim">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Sorry for the coding mess, I do not know where I copied it from... Apologies to make you lost time on this one with such silly mistakes! I will be more careful next time

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can do. you need to explore javascript more.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var tempobj = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for(var i=0;i<tempobj.length;i++)
    {
        tempobj[i].addEventListener('focus', function (elem) {
            console.log("on focus: "+elem.target.name);
        });         
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="signUp">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="fname"></label> -->
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="fname" name="user_name" placeholder="First Name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="lname"></label> -->
      <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="lname" name="user_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="email"></label> -->
      <input type="email" onfocus="this.value=''" id="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- <label for="password"></label> -->
      <input type="password" onfocus="this.value=''" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </li>
    <li class="button">
      <button type="submit" id="buttonClaim">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will and found already a couple of typos and logic errors..